# Rails 5 create multiple child objects using parent object by the use of nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, orm, nested-attributes

So, I'm fairly new to Rails and I'm stuck due to my model's complexity.

I have a `Developer` model, a `Township` model and a `Project` model and their contents are as follows:-

`Developer.rb`

```
Class Developer < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :townships,
  has_many :projects, through: :townships

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :township
end
```

`Township.rb`

```
Class Township < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :developer
  has_many :projects

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :project
end
```

`Project.rb`

```
Class Project < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :township

end
```

I want to create projects such as follows:-

```
project = Developer.create(
          {
           name: 'Lodha',
           township_attributes: [
            {
             name: 'Palava', 
             project_attributes: [
              {
               name: 'Central Park'
              },
              {
               name: 'Golden Tomorrow'
              }
            ]}
          ]})
```

Any ideas as to how can I accomplish this? I also need to understand the strong params whitelisting required in the `DeveloperController`.

Comment: are your associations correctly defined?

Comment: From what I understand, they are.

Comment: ok, but the relations are: 1) `Developer` is many-to-many with `Project` or 2) `Developer` has-many `Township` hast-many `Project`

Comment: Developer and township have a one to many and township and projects have a one to many mapping. So, developer and projects should have a one to many mapping as well through township.

Comment: is "a one to many"  a `has_many` association? or a `has_one` AND a `has_many` association in the same model at same time?

Comment: a `one to many` mapping is a `has_many` association though all children have a `belongs_to` association which is very similar to a `has_one` association.

Comment: yeah, but for convenience it's treated just as `has_many` association

Comment: Yes. In essence it's a `has_many` association.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of a way for you to create it in one line (plus it would be less readable) , but you can do this with rails using similar code to below:

```
def create
  developer = Developer.new(name: 'Loha')
  township = developer.townships.build({ name: 'Palava' })
    # for this part I don't know what your form looks like or what the 
    # params look like but the idea here is to loop through the project params like so
  params[:projects].each do |key, value|
    township.projects.build(name: value)
  end

  if developer.save
    redirect_to #or do something else
  end
end
```

Saving the developer will save all of the other things with the correct foreign keys assuming you have them set up correctly. Just pay attention to the format of your params to make sure you're looping through it correctly.

Comment: Thank you for your guidance. Yes, I understand your approach very well. I still do believe there must be a way to accomplish this in a go as the mapping is very simple and consistent. Regarding the model inheritance, Rails 5 now automatically generates an abstract class called `ApplicationRecord` which inherits `ActiveRecord::Base` so that no patching is to be done to customise or extend ActiveRecord's functionality.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the correction, I didn't know that.

Comment: Sure, always a pleasure. 