# How to create both a parent and nested elements at once with cocoon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, cocoon-gem

I have an `Edition` model that accepts nested attributes for a `Content` model. Is there anyway that I can create nested content at the same time as creating a new edition.

When creating the edition, it gives me the error:

`Contents edition can't be blank`.

From what I've read, this is because the edition hasn't been created yet, therefore, there is no `edition_id` to enter into the contents table.

I've tried setting the `inverse_of` option in both the edition and content models, but with no luck. I still get this error.

Here's my edition and content models:

```
class Content < ApplicationRecord
  validates_presence_of :heading, 
                        :link, 
                        :edition_id, 
                        :section_id

  belongs_to :edition, inverse_of: :contents
  belongs_to :section
  belongs_to :source, inverse_of: :contents
end

class Edition < ApplicationRecord
  validates_presence_of :date, :product_id

  belongs_to :product
  has_many :contents, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :edition
  has_many :sections, -> { distinct }, through: :contents

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :contents,
                                allow_destroy: true,
                                reject_if: lambda { |attrs| attrs['link'].blank? }
end
```

How could I fix this issue?

## Edit:

The server logs when creating the edition are:

```
Started POST "/editions" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-08-02 15:47:49 +0530
Processing by EditionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"QqSMYoMC76mCLPc6LI2ZvAyDih99J6erizPr2+CzAmLDCx3GALccQdLqbDoNaPNza1UAm8m62a8uHQdTwHV3AQ==", "edition"=>{"date(1i)"=>"2018", "date(2i)"=>"8", "date(3i)"=>"1", "product_id"=>"1", "contents_attributes"=>{"1533205044547"=>{"_destroy"=>"false", "heading"=>"Heading 2", "body"=>"<p>Text 12</p>", "section_id"=>"1", "link"=>"https://www.example.com/heading_2", "top_story"=>"0"}}}, "files"=>"", "commit"=>"Create Edition"}
  User Load (1.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (1.2ms)  BEGIN
  Product Load (1.3ms)  SELECT  "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Source Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "sources".* FROM "sources" WHERE "sources"."domain" = $1 ORDER BY "sources"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["domain", "www.example.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Section Load (0.9ms)  SELECT  "sections".* FROM "sections" WHERE "sections"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (1.5ms)  ROLLBACK
```

## Edit 2:

EditionsController create action and edition_params method:

```
def create
  @edition = Edition.new(edition_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @edition.save
      format.html { redirect_to @edition, notice: 'Edition was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @edition }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @edition.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

def edition_params
  params.require(:edition).permit(:date, 
                                  :clicks, 
                                  :product_id,
                                  contents_attributes: [:id,
                                                        :heading,
                                                        :body,
                                                        :link,
                                                        :top_story,
                                                        :section_id,
                                                        :_destroy
                                                       ]
                                 )
end
```

Comment: @JagdeepSingh I have edited the question with the server logs

Comment: Added the create action and the params used for it, @JagdeepSingh :)

Comment: Try the solution given below and let me know for further guidance, also feel free to accept/upvote answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far as i guess you have to build the object for `nested attributes` first i.e

```
def new
  @edition = Edition.new
  contents = @edition.contents.build
end
```

And in `create` action

```
def create
  @edition = Edition.new(edition_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @edition.save
      format.html { redirect_to @edition, notice: 'Edition was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @edition }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @edition.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

def edition_params
  params.require(:edition).permit(:date, 
                                  :clicks, 
                                  :product_id,
                                  contents_attributes: [:id,
                                                        :heading,
                                                        :body,
                                                        :link,
                                                        :top_story,
                                                        :section_id,
                                                        :_destroy
                                                       ]
                                 )
end
```

Remove validation for `edition_id`

```
class Content < ApplicationRecord
  validates_presence_of :heading, 
                        :link, 
                        :section_id

  belongs_to :edition, inverse_of: :contents
  belongs_to :section
  belongs_to :source, inverse_of: :contents
end
```

Comment: `@edition.contents.build` will return `content` (singular).

Comment: @JagdeepSingh Agree! but so far as i know `cocoon` gem handles itself as many number of nested object we want to create but at first it needs to provide a build nested object.

Comment: Nope, didn't work :(. I'm not sure that it's the contents that is the issue. I think it's just that the edition hasn't been created yet, so there is no `id` to assign to the nested contents. Is there a way to maybe create the edition and then create the contents? i.e. create them sequentially?

Comment: @UmarGhouse checkout this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42604103/rails-5-create-multiple-child-objects-using-parent-object-by-the-use-of-nested-a

Comment: @UmarGhouse Can you check updated answer, as i have seen you have added `content_id` witn validation presence  true, FYI, in rails 5, `belongs_to :content` means that it also required. remove that from validation and try again, hopefully this should work now.

Comment: @Gabbar that worked! It was the validation that was the issue! Just to note, I did not use this: `contents = @edition.contents.build` in the EditionsController#new action. Just removing the validation was all that was required! Thanks!

Comment: @UmarGhouse Cool, glad to know that, also remember this belongs_to automatically means that its required so it doesn't need to specify with validation. in case if it doesn't require then we use `optional: true`. anyway feel free to accept, upvote answer for future SO searchers.

Answer (score 1):

You can add optional: true in association this will solve your error, like this

```
belongs_to :edition, optional: true
```

Comment: `Optional: true`  this will easily let create child object without having parent, that's not right.

Comment: Yes, It will easily let create child object without parent but it depends on the requirement in case parent is not always necessary for child you can go for optional: true

Comment: Thanks! But, in my case the parent is required. Essentially, content should not exist without an edition.

Comment: Okay, then don't use optional: true if parent is necessary

Comment: Once the parent's validation failed the children are not c created s well. it works for rails 4. Upvote for the answer.